# XPath to select nodes in arbitrarily nested chains of a particular tag

Tags: xpath

In an example like this:

```
<body>

  <p id="0"/>

  <div>
    <p id="1"/>
  </div>

  <div>
    <div>
      <div>
        <p id="2"/>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <blockquote>
    <p id="3"/>
  </blockquote>

  <div>
    <blockquote>
      <div>
        <p id="4"/>
      </div>
    </blockquote>
  </div>

</body>
```

I want to select all `<p>` elements that are either a direct child of `<body>` or contained only in a chain of `<div>` elements, and nothing else. That is, I want to select ids 0, 1, and 2, but not 3 or 4. In regex parlance that would be something like `<body>(<div>)*<p>`. But can this be done with XPath? Some shorthand for `body/p | body/div/p | body/div/div/p | body/div/div/div/p | ...`?

ETA: Note that the `id` attributes are only present in this example for convenience, in my real application there are no `id`s.

Also, eventually I'm after an expression that can work with an arbitrary node as reference (and not just `<body>`), i.e., how to select nodes that are descendants of a reference node, but where any intermediate levels between them are `<div>`, and nothing else. Another way of putting it, I want nodes whose ancestors are all either `<div>` or ancestor-or-self of a particular reference node (not just a tag name, but a specific node).

When I say "reference node" I mean something to be used, e.g. with the Python `lxml` package:

```
reference_node.xpath( problem_expression )
```

Answer (score 2):

What comes to my mind is :

```
//p[count(ancestor::div)=count(ancestor::*[ancestor::body])]
```

Output : id=0, id=1, id=2

Comment: Hmm... How would I do if instead of `<body>` I want to say "this current node". So, from `<body>` I would select ids 0, 1, 2, but from the first `<blockquote>` I would select id 3 and from the second, id 4. Can I somehow say `[ancestor::(the-very-first-element-I-started-from)]`?

Comment: The part `[ancestor::body]` of the XPath is here to remove the `body` element from the results in the second count step. Writing  `[not(name()="body")]` will work too. I don't understand what you're trying to achieve. I don't get it with the "current node" (".", in XPath language), or "element-I-started-from". I thought  you didn't want to select id3 and id4... To select from the blockquotes, why don't you use : `//blockquote//p[@id]` ? If you could describe with more details what you want exactly (elements to extract, conditions for the XPath expression,...), that would be great.

Comment: I hope I've fully understood your needs. Is `body/p|//*[descendant::*[last()][name()="p"]][count(descendant::*)-1=count(descendant::div)]//p` good for you ? http://xpather.com/gbLfJpdq

Comment: That just selects all `<p>`s, at least in this example (or the link does not work right for me). And it doesn't select a `<p>` if it contains something else. Perhaps you understood my requirement as "any `<p>` that's contained in a chain of 0 or more `<div>`s from any node" (which would indeed select any `<p>` whatsoever). What I'm after is an expression that would select such `<div>`-contained `<p>`s relative to some arbitrary element (which could be the root element, or one particular `<blockquote>` or whatever), where this arbitrary element changes from run to run.

Comment: "Perhaps you understood my requirement as "any <p> that's contained in a chain of 0 or more <div>s from any node" (which would indeed select any <p> whatsoever)." Yes. You can declare the arbitrary element in the first part of the expression I've written. For example, if `/body/blockquote[1]` is your reference node : `/body/blockquote[1][descendant::*[last()][name()="p"]][count(descendant::*)-1=count(descendant::div)]//p` Another way of putting it : `/body/blockquote[1]//p[count(ancestor::div)=count(/body/blockquote[1]/descendant::*) or count(/body/blockquote[1]/descendant::*)=1]`

Comment: Well, it still doesn't make it if the `<p>`s have any other `<p>` siblings (or anything else after), or if they have any children. I still want to select the `<p>`s, I don't care about their content or their siblings or order. I only care about the elements which are simultaneously ancestors to the `<p>` and children to my "arbitrary element": they must all be `<div>`.

Comment: With `/body/blockquote` as reference, this will work : `/body/blockquote//p[count(ancestor::div[ancestor::body/blockquote])-count(body/blockquote/self::div)=count(ancestor::*[ancestor::body/blockquote])-1]` This will also work when the node reference is a `div`. Is this OK ?

Comment: It seems to work, although it's quite inconvenient that the reference node has to be repeated in several places (XSLT's `current()` would probably be helpful). But I guess it's now clear that XPath simply doesn't have the feature I wanted.

Comment: Is `ancestor::body/blockquote` supposed to mean `(ancestor::body)/blockquote` or `ancestor::(body/blockquote)`. It seems to me we'd like the latter, but it actually means the former. At least `//div[ancestor::body/blockquote]` selects all `<div>`s and it's not equivalent to `//body/blockquote//div`.

Comment: `ancestor::body/blockquote` means `ancestor::body/child::blockquote`. First part is evaluated, then the second. So yes, the former option `(ancestor::body)/blockquote`. Writing `ancestor::/body/blockquote` would throw an error.